# How to fix error regarding image not found if there is a mime type json?

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api

I got this code in my `web.config`

```
<staticContent>
      <remove fileExtension=".svg"/>
      <remove fileExtension=".svgz"/>
      <remove fileExtension=".eot"/>
      <remove fileExtension=".otf"/>
      <remove fileExtension=".woff"/>
      <remove fileExtension=".jpeg"/>
      <remove fileExtension=".jpg"/>
      <remove fileExtension=".gif"/>
      <remove fileExtension=".png"/>
      <remove fileExtension=".bmp"/>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".jpeg" mimeType="image/jpeg"/>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".jpg" mimeType="image/jpeg"/>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".gif" mimeType="image/gif"/>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".png" mimeType="image/png"/>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".bmp" mimeType="image/bmp"/>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml"/>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".svgz" mimeType="image/svg+xml"/>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".eot" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-fontobject"/>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".otf" mimeType="font/otf"/>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="font/x-woff"/>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json"/>
    </staticContent>
```

Now the problem is the image in my web got an error like this.

`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)`

But whe i remove the `<mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json"/>`
the image is rendered properly but the json file i have is not found.

How to fix this error regarding `json` mimetype and image. I want both of them found in my web.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Look for more details than simply "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)"

Does asp.net have a debug mode to make errors more verbose? If so enable it. 
Check logs for more details.

A wild guess (limited by the level of detail given) is that you mess up the XML somehow and it fails. 
Could you provide a link to the entire files w/ and w/o the mimeMap ?
(And be perfectly certain that one work and one fails..)
Then people can look for the error.

<s>Another take: 
Maybe you're lacking to define the .json file. 
Try to add:
`<remove fileExtension=".json"/>`</s>

Comment: yes i have that `<remove fileExtension=".json"/>` and still not working

Comment: Ok. Updated accordingly response. Note that you question doesn't reflect this. I suggest you edit it.